# Étiquettes de l'axe des abscisses et des ordonnées dans un graphique : singulier ou pluriel?

Tags: pluriel

Dans un graphique, dois-je écrire les étiquettes de l'axe des abscisses et des ordonnées au singulier ou au pluriel ?

Singulier:

[image]

Pluriel :

[image]

Comment: L’étiquette « serveur » n’est pas très clair. Est-ce le *nombre de serveur* ou le *numéro du serveur* ?

Comment: @Édouard Oui, l'exemple que j'ai choisi n'est pas terrible, j'étais vraiment en manque d'inspiration ce matin. Au regard des réponses reçues, j'en déduis que si "serveur" désigne le "nombre de serveurs", alors il faut le mettre au pluriel, et si "serveur" désigne le "numéro du serveur", alors il faut le mettre au singulier. Quant à la durée, en présumant qu'un point du graphique ne contient qu'une seule durée, alors durée doit être écrit au singulier.

Comment: Très franchement, je dirai que si « serveur » désigne le nombre de serveur, il faut mettre « nombre de serveurs » au singulier, si « serveur » désigne le numéro de serveur, il faut utiliser « numéro de serveur » au singulier.

Answer (score 9):

Dans un graphique, il est souhaitable que les unités utilisées soient précisées, voici un exemple de ce que j'afficherais:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

*Serveurs*, 
 puisque vous en affichez 16 au maximum.

Pour les substantifs, c'est une question de présentation  de l'expérience.

S'il n'y a qu'un traitement qui utilise *X* serveurs, la *durée* est singulière :

> pour *n* serveurs simultanément actifs, la *durée* est de *t*.

S'il s'agit d'une moyenne de plusieurs relevés par serveurs, *durées* est au pluriel, à moins que vous n'indiquiez *durée moyenne* ; mais on peut aussi laisser au singulier car de toute façon, il n'y a qu'une *durée* qui intéresse le lecteur.

Answer (score 0):

En l'occurrence, chaque point correspond à une durée et un serveur (donc la logique voudrait que ce soit au singulier).
De plus, lorsque l'on lit le graphique on cherche une durée pour un serveur donné et non pas à voir toutes les durées à la fois.

Orthographe mise à part, pour ce genre de graphique, il est préférable d'utiliser un diagramme à barres, car comme je l'ai dit plus haut, on y lit les durées une par une.

Comment: Non, l'intension était bien d'avoir un nombre et pas un numéro de serveur en abscisses, d'après les clarifications que l'auteur de la question a apporté en commentaires.